# Dart implementing a class would also inherit its fields?

Tags: dart

I'm reading Language Tour of Dart https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#implicit-interfaces:

```
class Person {

  final _name; /* this is the field of Person */

  ...
}


class Impostor implements Person {

  get _name => ''; /* so it's inherited? */

  String greet(String who) => 'Hi $who. Do you know who I am?';
}
```

In Java there are only constants(`public static final` thing) in interface. So it seems like `Impostor` also inherits the `final _name` from `Person`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So it seems like `Impostor` also inherits the `final _name` from `Person`?

It depends.

## Privacy

If the implementing class is in the same *library* as the base (usually this means a different Dart file), then the base class's private interface will be visible to the implementing class and must be implemented as well.

If the implementing class is in a *different* library, then the base class's private interface will not be visible, and the implementing class is not expected to implement the private members.

## Fields

(Visible) fields are part of the class's *interface*.  An implementing class is required to implement that visible interface.  If the base class has a public field, that really just means that its interface exposes public *getter* and *setter* methods with that name.

You can observe this yourself.  If you put both of the following classes in the same Dart file:

```
class Base {
  Base() : _x = 42;

  final int _x;

  void _f() {}
}

class Derived implements Base {
}
```

You'll get an error:

```
Error: The non-abstract class 'Derived' is missing implementations for these members:
 - Base._f
 - Base._x
Try to either
 - provide an implementation,
 - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
 - mark the class as abstract, or
 - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation
```

But putting them in separate `base.dart` and `derived.dart` files (where `derived.dart` adds `import 'base.dart';`), then it will be accepted.

Comment: Thank you so much... That dart provides default getter/setter is what I forgot...

Answer (score 0):

From Documentation:

> Unlike Java, Dart does not have the keywords public, protected, and
>   private. If an identifier starts with an underscore _, it’s private to
>   its library.

What it means that privacy exist at library level rather than class level.

To use that in other files you will need to import the library in your file.

Comment: This question doesn't answer the main question about how `implements` works with (possibly private) fields.